# What is difference in iPhone os 3.0 and 3.0.1

Tags: iphone

Developing for iphone os 3.0 and 3.0.1 make some difference or not?

Comment: I don't believe the API changed, 3.0.1 is just a bug fix release.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there's no difference for developers. They just fixed the SMS bug. Most of the binaries are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Developing yes, you need to [create a simlink](http://adcdownload.apple.com/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.0__final/iphone_os_3.0.1_advisory.pdf) to get a deployment to work properly.

From a user's prospective, no. This fix was a bit of an emergency release, solely to fix an SMS vulnerability.